# Grouping columns with similar column names into one in R

Tags: r, join, pivot, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| REQID | REQID22 | REQID433 | PRODUCTID | PRODUCTID12 | PRODUCTID236 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K01123 | NA | NA | NA | P0349-93 | NA |
| NA | K03843-02 | NA | P043953-12 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | K0349-93 | P45948 | NA | NA |
| K023834-02 | NA | NA | NA | NA | P03483-09 |

I need to find the unique RequirementID - ProductID combinations that are **given** in the table, but as you can see I have three RequirementID columns and three ProductID columns. I need to find all REQ-PRODUCTID combinations that occur in the table and not create combinations myself. After having done several attempts with the *pivotlonger *and *join *functions, I haven't succeeded in solving this problem.

So in the end I want to create a table with two columns: REQID and PRODUCTID and the existing combinations as rows. See table below:

| RequirementID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| K01123 | P0349-93 |
| K03843-02 | P043953-12 |
| K0349-93 | P45948 |
| K023834-02 | P03483-09 |

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to find the Req - ProductID combinations that are available in the table. So I should not create other combinations that don't exist.

Comment: @Ben any ideas for that?

Comment: I added another table with the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (I just used a couple of for loops to go through
the dataframe)

```
df  <- read.csv("data.csv")   
df
#output
> df
   REQID   REQID22 REQID433  PRODUCTID PRODUCTID12 PRODUCTID236
1     K01123      <NA>     <NA>       <NA>       P0349         <NA>
2       <NA> K03843-02     <NA> P043953-12        <NA>         <NA>
3       <NA>      <NA> K0349-93     P45948        <NA>         <NA>
4 K023834-02      <NA>     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>    P03483-09
> 
 
#create a couple of empty containers.           
df2<-c()
df3 <-c()
for(i in 1:length(df)){
     for(j in 1:length(colnames(df))){
       #find the 2 items that are not NAs
       if(!is.na(df[i,j])){
         df2<- cbind(df2, df[i,j])
       }
     }
     #add the items to the list
     df3<-rbind(df3,df2)
      df2<-c()
    }  

}

df3
```

cheers
Candy

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the following error: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Answer (score 0):

We can unite multiple columns into one with `tidyr::unite()`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df_ %>% 
  unite("REQID", starts_with("REQID"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  unite("PRODUCTID", starts_with("PRODUCTID"), na.rm = TRUE) 
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   REQID      PRODUCTID 
#>   <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1 K01123     P0349-93  
#> 2 K03843-02  P043953-12
#> 3 K0349-93   P45948    
#> 4 K023834-02 P03483-09
```

Input data:

```r
df_ <- readr::read_table("
REQID   REQID22 REQID433    PRODUCTID   PRODUCTID12 PRODUCTID236
K01123  NA  NA  NA  P0349-93    NA
NA  K03843-02   NA  P043953-12  NA  NA
NA  NA  K0349-93    P45948  NA  NA
K023834-02  NA  NA  NA  NA  P03483-09")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't want to create combinations that don't exist. I only need the ones that are given in the table. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: Sure, just skip expand.

Answer (score 0):

We can also `reduce` the `coalesce` function:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
    mutate(RequirementID = reduce(pick(starts_with("REQ")),
                                       \(x,y) coalesce(x, y)),
           product = reduce(pick(starts_with("PRODUCT")),
                                       \(x,y) coalesce(x, y)),
           .keep = "unused")

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  RequirementID product   
  <chr>         <chr>     
1 K01123        P0349-93  
2 K03843-02     P043953-12
3 K0349-93      P45948    
4 K023834-02    P03483-09
```